# Al activar o desactivar un checkbox se me borra lo escrito en los inputs asociados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

un listado de checkbox, los cuales se me cargan a través de un JSON realizando un bucle y cuando selecciono un checkbox se me habilita un input donde puedo escribir un número. El error me da cuando tras seleccionar un checkbox y escribir en el input relacionado, selecciono otro checkbox para habilitar otro input, pero al seleccionar el segundo checkbox, lo que tenía escrito en el los inputs se me borra y no sé por qué.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Species</h3>
        <section>
          <p id="zona_especie">-</p>
          <div class="form-group wd-xs-600">
            <label class="form-control-label">Specie: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
            <div id="myDiv_especie"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="especie_seleccionada" id="especie_seleccionada">

          </div><!-- form-group -->
        </section>
```

**Javascript** el cual carga todo el listado de los checkbox, título e inputs relacionados

```
  var array3 = json_especies;
var numSpecies;

function desactivar() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
        if ($("#especie" + i).is(':checked')) {
            $("#cantSpecies" + i).removeAttr('disabled');
            //numSpecies.setAttribute('value', '1');
            $("#cantSpecies" + i).val('value', '1');
        } else {
            $("#cantSpecies" + i).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            //numSpecies.setAttribute('value', '0');
            $("#cantSpecies" + i).val('value', '0');
        }
    }
}   

// Reusable Function to Enforce MaxLength
function enforce_maxlength(event) {
    var t = event.target;
    if (t.hasAttribute('maxlength')) {
        t.value = t.value.slice(0, t.getAttribute('maxlength'));
    }
}

// Global Listener for anything with an maxlength attribute.
// I put the listener on the body, put it on whatever.
document.body.addEventListener('input', enforce_maxlength);


function GetCheckedVal() {
    //alert('entra funcion GetCheckedVal')

    $('#myDiv_especie').change(function() {
        var values = []; {
            $('#myDiv_especie :checked').each(function() {
                //if(values.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1){
                values.push($(this).val());
                // }
            });
            console.log(values);
        }
    });


    /*document.getElementsByName("especie").forEach(function(element) {
        if (element.checked) {

            alert(element.value);

            document.getElementById("zona_especie").innerHTML = element.value;

            //store the checked value in a hidden field control, 
            //and then you can get the value from code behind
            document.getElementById("especie_seleccionada").value = element.value;
        }
    })*/
} 

$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    var myDiv3 = document.getElementById("myDiv_especie");
    //Create array of options to be added


    // Species List
    var table_rdb_list = document.createElement("table");
    table_rdb_list.setAttribute("id", "especiesList");

    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    //Create and append the options

    for (var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {

        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");

        var radioList = document.createElement("input");
        radioList.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        radioList.setAttribute('id', 'especie' + i);
        radioList.setAttribute('name', 'especie');
        radioList.setAttribute('value', array3[i].id);
        radioList.setAttribute('onChange', 'GetCheckedVal()');
        radioList.setAttribute('onClick', 'desactivar()');

        radioList.onchange = function() {
            GetCheckedVal();

        }
        radioList.onClick = function() {
            desactivar();
        }

        //radioList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
        lbl.setAttribute("for", "especie" + i);
        lbl.setAttribute("class", "ckbox ckbox-success pos-left-10");

        var t = document.createTextNode(array3[i].nombre + '/' + array3[i].cientifico);


        numSpecies = document.createElement("input");
        numSpecies.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('min', '1');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('max', '99');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('maxlength', '2');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('value', '0');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('id', 'cantSpecies' + i);
        numSpecies.setAttribute('name', 'cantSpecies');
        numSpecies.setAttribute("class", "cantEspecies");
        numSpecies.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

        lbl.appendChild(t);
        td.appendChild(radioList);
        td.appendChild(lbl);
        td.appendChild(numSpecies);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);

    }

    table_rdb_list.appendChild(tbody);

    myDiv3.appendChild(table_rdb_list);

});
```

Con esto, se me carga correctamente todo el listado de checkbox con su título correspondiente y el input desactivado. Selecciono un checkbox y se me activa el input asociado a dicho checkbox y escribo algo en el input, al seleccionar el siguiente checkbox para habilitar el siguiente input, al parecer me hace el bucle correspondiente para ver que checkbox está seleccionado y cual no y al realizar dicho bucle, borra el input o inputs que estaban escritos.

Qué puedo estar haciendo mal para que me pase esto y se me borren los inputs cuando selecciono o deselecciono un checkbox?

Muchas gracias

Comment: buenas, sinceramente no sé lo que hice ni lo que toqué pero ya me funcionó, ahora me estoy pegando en eliminar el valor del value del input que cuando se desactiva el check, se me queda el value, pero esa ya es otro tema. Muchas gracias